# SQL Server select query assistance needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working on building a query but have a difficult time coming up with the right solutions. Here's what my data looks like...

I have about 10,000 records - bills in my `tblBilling`.

- Each record has a unique ID number ranging from about 10 - 13000.
- However my primary key is the `BillNo` which in my records is a 1.
- In case that bill was refunded, another line is added into the tbl but in this case the BillNo is 2.
- Additionally I have another column called `AdjType` which can either be A, B, C

  - when BillNo is 2, AdjType = B
  - but for normal BillNo 1 - the value is NULL.

So it looks like this...

**tblBilling**

```
ID  BillNo  Units  TotalPaid  AdjType
-------------------------------------
10  2       17     230        NULL
```

So this is a normal Bill where BillNO is 1 - this means that it was a PAID Bill.

Additionally you might have BIllNO2 which is most likely a refund that would look like this....

```
ID  BillNo  Units  TotalPaid  AdjType
--------------------------------------
10  2       -17    -230       B
```

So here we are negating Units because its a refund and in this case ADJType = B

Both together if I SELECT * from tblBilling where ID=10 I get this....

```
ID   BillNo   Units   TotalPaid   AdjType
-----------------------------------------
10     1       17       230       NULL
10     2      -17      -230       B
```

Now my main goal is to select all records from `tblBilling`, however I don't want to select any records that have a BillNo 2 associated with them. Basically if a record has BillNO = 1 - that's the record I need. No records that have BillNo=2. Please help!

Comment: BillNo is a PK or a Flag Field?

Comment: You can probably use NOT EXISTS for this quite easily. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza PK

Comment: Then rewrite your question, right now looks like you are talking of a flag, because you say can have value 1 or 2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza done sorry for not being clear

Comment: imo the question needs a major rewrite. the primary key column ranging 10-13000 is missing from the sample. the `ID` column looks like the 'bill ID' and not the table primary key since the data sample contain duplicate values for `ID`. from my guesswork on the question the natural key could be (ID,BillNo) so a separate primary key should not be needed.

Comment: @Paolo that the ID column - it can contain duplicate values as long as BillNo is not the same. I'll be more clear in the future. My apologies. got the answer already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from tblBilling t1
where t1.AdjType is NULL
  and not exists(select 1 from tblBilling t2
    where t2.id = t1.id and t2.AdjType = 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tblBilling
WHERE
    ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM tblBilling WHERE BillNo = 2)
```

Comment: That will give me all the records - however a lot of those records were refunded so I wnt to make sure that the records where BillNo=1, don't have BillNo=2 associated with them. I need to edit the Bills but if they were already refunded (BillNo=2) then I can't adjust them.

Comment: I updated the code so you will get no adjusted values.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tblBilling a 
where not exists (select * from tblbilling b where a.id=b.id and a.billno<>b.billno)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblBilling A
WHERE A.BillNo = 1
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM tblBilling B 
        WHERE A.id=B.id 
            AND B.BillNo =2
            AND A.Units= (-1 * B.Units)
            AND A.TotalPaid= (-1 * B.TotalPaid)
    )
```